# How to use Google Cloud Endpoints from within a Chrome App?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-chrome-app, google-api-client

I'm building a Chrome app, and I'd really like it to communicate with my server over cloud endpoints, but there are two problems that I'm not sure how to overcome:

1. The Google apis javascript library is an external script, which I can't use in a page in a chrome app. Can I just copy the source of the library, and place it in a file in my app's source?
2. The client checks your javascript origin, but an extension's origin is of the form `chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID`, which the developer console doesn't accept as a javascript origin.

How do I get around these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Loading the gapi client**

Indeed the only way I have found to load the gapi client is to use a webview, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112738/google-drive-realtime-api-in-a-chrome-packaged-app). I have tested itand it works well but weirdly the authentication does not work at all, and Cloud Endpoints believes you're anonymous.

In addition communication from a webview to the rest of the world is pretty tricky (window.postMessage does not allow to send a response in a callback).

I think you will be better off calling directly the REST methods using AJAX requests, with a helper such as jQuery or other. You just have to set the `Authorization` header using you access token, like this in jQuery :

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+THE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
            },
            url: "https://yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/yourapi/v1/yourmethod",
            success: function(msg) {
                //Put here your callback
            }
    });
```

See below how to get the access token.

**2. Authorization in Chrome Apps**

You do not have to worry about the origin part in Chrome Apps, you simply need to generate a client id specific to the Chrome App, and use the Chrome Identity API to get authorization from the user. Check the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) documentation for more details.

Note that since you will need to create a new client id, you will need to update your Google Cloud Endpoint's configuration to add this client id to the list of authorized clients.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.  There are several GAPI packages for Angular in bower.
2. The Tasks sample app says it uses the GAPI.  Check the example there:
   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/tasks

Hope that helps!

Comment: That version of the client library doesn't implement `gapi.client.load`, which I need to load my Cloud Endpoints api, buy maybe I can implement it in a similar way to how gapi.execute is implemented.

Comment: @bigblind I don't see any reason you couldn't use a different version.

Comment: With vesion, I mean that implementation. The

Comment: What implementation do you want to use?